# Fetch data from two tables and add the values with same date in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables named as `cash` and `bank` both the tables have same attributes

```
`( `id` VARCHAR, `person_id` VARCHAR, `date` DATE, `remarks` VARCHAR, `type` VARCHAR, `amount` INTEGER, `balance` INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(`id`)
)`
```

Now I need an SQLite query to fetch the total income/expenses of a particular date by adding the cash amount and bank amount

Comment: total income/expenses on what basis?? Like per person, per date, per type or combination of few columns?

Comment: based on `type` attribute. it strores `in` for income and `out` for expense

Comment: I removed the incompatible tags since your title says you are using SQLite.

Comment: one more thing I want to tell you. The column name `date` stores `datetime`

Comment: There is no `datetime` type in SQLite, dates are stored as text.  Can you show us a sample of data stored in your `date` column?

Comment: I know that, what I'm trying to tell you is date column do stores data in the form of datetime `(yyyy-mm-dd h:m:s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the amount sum based on the `date` and `type`, it can be done as below:

```
select type,date,sum(amount) total
from
(
    select type,amount,date
    from cash
    union all
    select type,amount,date
    from bank 
) t
group by type,SUBSTR(date,0,10)
```

Comment: This query is returning multiple rows of the same date with different amount, I want to add all the amount with same date

Comment: I just added `GROUP BY SUBSTR(date,0,10)` to your query and now I'm getting the desired result. Thanks

Comment: Ok, as sample data is not given so I belive that it should be date only, However from your comment I got that you are storing the date & time both so you need to remove the time part, I'll update my answer.